# Dialogflow convo not displaying on screen

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, flutter-dependencies

So I'm trying to do a chatbot for my application and everything works fine except that the conversation between me and the chatbot does not display on the my application screen... however, I can see the chatbot reply to my queries in the vscode terminal. can someone tell me why?

below is my code..

```
import 'package:bubble/bubble.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dialogflow/dialogflow_v2.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class ChatBot extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatBotState createState() => _ChatBotState();
}

class _ChatBotState extends State<ChatBot> {
  final chatController = TextEditingController();
  List<Map> messages = new List();

  void response(query) async {
    chatController.clear();
    AuthGoogle authGoogle =
        await AuthGoogle(fileJson: "assets/Dialogflowservice/ChatbotStark.json")
            .build();
    Dialogflow dialogflow =
        Dialogflow(authGoogle: authGoogle, language: Language.english);
    AIResponse aiResponse = await dialogflow.detectIntent(query);
    setState(() {
      messages.insert(0, {
        "data": 0,
        "messages": aiResponse.getListMessage()[0]["text"]["text"][0].toString()
      });
    });

    print(aiResponse.getListMessage()[0]["text"]["text"][0].toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Chatbot",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Futura', fontSize: 17.sp),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
          toolbarHeight: 45.h,
          automaticallyImplyLeading:
              false, // remove the back button from appbar
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                  child: Container(
                      height: 35.h,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.h),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "${DateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm").format(DateTime.now())}",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Futura', fontSize: 12.5.sp),
                      ))),
              Flexible(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      reverse: true,
                      itemCount: 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => chat(
                          messages[index]["messages"].toString(),
                          messages[index]["data"]))),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15.h,
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 60.h,
                  width: 500.w,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(width: 15.w),
                      Container(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 4),
                        height: 40.h,
                        width: 350.w,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          controller: chatController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "what's on your mind?",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Futura', fontSize: 13.sp),
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Futura',
                            fontSize: 13.sp,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                          iconSize: 22.sp,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (chatController.text.isEmpty) {
                              print("empty message");
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                messages.insert(0, {
                                  "data": 1,
                                  "message": chatController.text
                                });
                              });
                              response(chatController.text);
                            }
                            FocusScopeNode currentFocus =
                                FocusScope.of(context);
                            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                              currentFocus.unfocus();
                            }
                          })
                    ],
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

Widget chat(String message, int data) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment:
          data == 1 ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        data == 0
            ? Container(
                height: 60.h,
                width: 60.w,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      AssetImage("assets/images/Robotics-pana-3 copy.png"),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),

        // Chat Bubble
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Bubble(
            radius: Radius.circular(15),
            color: data == 0
                ? Colors.amber[50]
                : Colors.grey[300], // if bot it is amber, if it is user grey
            elevation: 0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.w,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200.w),
                    child: Text(
                      message,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Futura',
                        fontSize: 13.sp,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        data == 1
            ? Container(
                height: 60.h,
                width: 60.w,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      AssetImage("assets/images/Robotics-pana-3 copy.png"),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I know it is a bit long... I'm new to flutter so I don't know what is missing and hoping that others can spot something

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not creating correctly your message list. You set the itemCount of your list to 0, so it might be the problem :

```
 Flexible(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      reverse: true,
                      itemCount: messages.length, // instead of 0
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => chat(
                          messages[index]["messages"].toString(),
                          messages[index]["data"]))),
```

If it's notthe solution, try to initialise the list with 2-3 messages on your app starting (override initState and insert fake messages). So you'll validate that the list is correctly displayed, and guess that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: hi so your solution does help, thank you! But now I can see that my chat bubble for the user side display "null" instead of what I wrote eg: "hi" or "how are you" ... but the chatbot still can reply to my queries correctly, why is that?

Comment: Check the value of the data your using. The conversion of the object json -> object might be wrong or the display object -> list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this might help:

```dart
import 'package:bubble/bubble.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dialogflow/dialogflow_v2.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

List<Map> messages = new List();

class ChatBot extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatBotState createState() => _ChatBotState();
}

class _ChatBotState extends State<ChatBot> {
  final chatController = TextEditingController();

  void response(query) async {
    chatController.clear();
    AuthGoogle authGoogle =
        await AuthGoogle(fileJson: "assets/Dialogflowservice/ChatbotStark.json")
            .build();
    Dialogflow dialogflow =
        Dialogflow(authGoogle: authGoogle, language: Language.english);
    AIResponse aiResponse = await dialogflow.detectIntent(query);
    setState(() {
      messages.insert(0, {
        "data": 0,
        "messages": aiResponse.getListMessage()[0]["text"]["text"][0].toString()
      });
    });

    print(aiResponse.getListMessage()[0]["text"]["text"][0].toString());
  }


  // Added this:
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    messages = new List();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Chatbot",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Futura', fontSize: 17.sp),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
          toolbarHeight: 45.h,
          automaticallyImplyLeading:
              false, // remove the back button from appbar
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                  child: Container(
                      height: 35.h,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.h),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "${DateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm").format(DateTime.now())}",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Futura', fontSize: 12.5.sp),
                      ))),
              Flexible(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      reverse: true,
                      // Changes here:
                      itemCount: messages.length(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => chat(
                          messages[index]["messages"].toString(),
                          messages[index]["data"]))),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15.h,
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 60.h,
                  width: 500.w,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(width: 15.w),
                      Container(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 4),
                        height: 40.h,
                        width: 350.w,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          controller: chatController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "what's on your mind?",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Futura', fontSize: 13.sp),
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Futura',
                            fontSize: 13.sp,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                          iconSize: 22.sp,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (chatController.text.isEmpty) {
                              print("empty message");
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                messages.insert(0, {
                                  "data": 1,
                                  "message": chatController.text
                                });
                              });
                              response(chatController.text);
                            }
                            FocusScopeNode currentFocus =
                                FocusScope.of(context);
                            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                              currentFocus.unfocus();
                            }
                          })
                    ],
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: hi so your solution does help, but now I can see that my chat bubble for the user side display "null" instead of what I wrote eg: "hi" or "how are you" ... but the chatbot still can reply to my queries correctly, why is that?

Comment: I don't know if your chat controller contains the appropriate text. Can you print the value of the text? Maybe, it is just sending 'null' as a query to the chatbot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had written the message inside the quote with an 's' when it is supposed to be just "message'